# Getting unrecognizable error in jquery function

Tags: jquery

Im getting an error on my each function 
Im trying to combine all inputs in one each statement but its throwing me an error in inspect tool.

HTML CODE

```
<input type="text" name="publishername[]" class="form-control publishername">
<input type="text" name="publisherlocation[]" class="form-control publisherlocation" >
<input type="text" name="publisheremail[]" class="form-control publisheremail">
```

script function

```
$("input[name='publishername[]' ,input[name='publisherlocation[]' , input[name='publisheremail[]'  ").each(function () { /// error here
```

This is how i send my data to my query. Im trying to achieve this kind of output. If the entered data in the textboxs exist it will perform an update to the data instead otherwise it will insert the data to my table.

```
    $(document).on("click", "#btn_add_publisher", function(event) {
    var getpublishers = [];
    event.preventDefault();
    $("input[name='publishername[]'], input[name='publisherlocation[]'], input[name='publisheremail[]']").each(function() {

        var getpublishername = $("publishername").val();
        var getpublisherlocation = $("publisherlocation").val();
        var getpublisheremail = $("publisheremail").val();
        var whatprocess = "add_publisher_process";
        $.ajax({
            url: "adminfunctions.php",
            async: false,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                getpublishername: getpublishername,
                getpublisherlocation: getpublisherlocation,
                getpublisheremail: getpublisheremail,
                whatprocess: whatprocess
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var getdata = data.trim();
                getpublishers.push(getdata);
                if (getdata == "SUCCESSINSERT") {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Success!',
                        text: 'Publisher Added',
                        type: 'success',
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success",
                        buttonsStyling: false
                    }, function() {

                    });
                } else if (getdata == "SUCCESSUPDATED") {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Success!',
                        text: 'Publisher Updated',
                        type: 'success',
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success",
                        buttonsStyling: false
                    }, function() {

                    });
                } else if (getdata == "ERROREMPTY") {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Oops..',
                        text: 'You must enter a value to proceed',
                        type: 'warning',
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-warning",
                        buttonsStyling: false
                    }).catch(swal.noop)
                } else {
                    swal({
                        title: 'Sorry for the inconvenience!',
                        text: "There's a problem. Please contact the technical support for any concerns and questions.!",
                        type: 'error',
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-info",
                        buttonsStyling: false
                    }, function() {

                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });


    });

});
```

Select query

```
$query = "SELECT publisher_name , publisher_location , publisher_email FROM tbl_publisher_add WHERE publisher_name = ? AND publisher_location = ? AND publisher_email = ?";
```

Dynamic Textbox Image
[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaRV7.png)

It only inserts the first textbox data 
[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q84NY.png)

Console Log [console log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkY0M.png)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen no need as the value is in quotes

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the elements individually, not as one group:

```
$("input[name='publishername[]'], input[name='publisherlocation[]'], input[name='publisheremail[]']").each(function () {
  // your logic...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give class to each element and by class you can acces each element value

```
<form id="publisherForm">
<input type="text" name="publisher[name][]" class="data form-control publishername">
<input type="text"  name="publisher[location][]" class="data form-control 
 publisherlocation" >
 <input type="text"  name="publisher[email][]" class="data form-control publisheremail">
 </form>
```

Script file

```
var form = $('#publisherForm');
$.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url: your url,
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  }
} );
```

Now access the variable in server file as `$_POST['publisher']`
Using  you can access each by

```
$publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
$index=0;
$namearr=$publisher['name'];
foreach($namearr as $value){
 $name=$value;
 $location=$publisher['location'][$index];
 $email=$publisher['email'][$index];
 $index++;
 $query = "SELECT publisher_name , publisher_location , publisher_email FROM tbl_publisher_add WHERE publisher_name = ".$name." AND publisher_location = ".$location." AND publisher_email = ".$email." ";
}
```